# R - Look for a string on multiple conditions and replace it in a new colum

Tags: regex, r, search, replace

I have a data frame where the main columns are: `"source"` and `"Medium"`. What i need is to depending of the values of `"source"` and `"Medium"` to assign a `"value"` on a new column, named `"Campanas1"`.

**The problem is:**

When doing it with my code (see below) the values of my col `"contentGroupUniqueViews1"`  does not match with the original data frame. And the code is a little confusing (not compact).

Is there a way to:

**Work in the data.frame, and apply an ifelse series of conditions to output the result in a New column?**  ***I don't want to subset and then rejoin, because it has a high risk of dupplicating rows.***

*Is there a simpler way of doing ifelse Search & Replace in a new column?
Or at least do this, so my values match to the original ones? I think the problem is in the regex for the referrals, but i'm not seeing it right now.*

**These are my steps:**

1. Subset on multiple conditions (combining this 2 columns).
2. Create a new column with the new value i need. e.g. `If "souce" == "google" and "Medium" == organic" then "Búsquedas"`.
3. I put this subsets in new variables: `Directo`, `Búsquedas`, `Adwords`, `Social_Media`, `Email`, `Referencias`, `RRSS`.
4. Then use `rbind` to join all the subsets to recreate the original one.

**This is my code:**

```
Directo <- subset(x = Total_Content, grepl("\\(direct\\)", source))
Directo$Campanas1 <- "Directo"

Búsquedas <- subset(x = Total_Content, grepl("google", source) & grepl("organic", Medium))
Búsquedas$Campanas1 <- "Búsquedas"

Adwords <- subset(Total_Content, grepl("google", source) & grepl("cpc", Medium) | grepl("cpv",      Medium))
Adwords$Campanas1 <- "Adwords"

Social_Media <- subset(Total_Content, grepl(".*faceb.*", source) | grepl("social\\-media",   Medium))
Social_Media$Campanas1 <- "Social Media"

Email <- subset(Total_Content, grepl(".*mail.*", source) | grepl(".*mail.*", Medium))
Email$Campanas1 <- "Email"

RRSS <- subset(Total_Content, grepl(".*terra.*", source) | grepl("elcomercio", source)|   grepl("diario16", source)| grepl(".*laprensa.*", source))
RRSS$Campanas1 <- "RRSS"

Referencias <- subset(Total_Content, grepl(".*esp.*", source) & !grepl(".*faceb.*", source) &     !grepl(".*mail.*", source) &  !grepl(".*comercio.*", source) &  !grepl(".*prensa.*", source) &     !grepl(".*diario.*", source) &  !grepl(".*terra.*", source) & grepl("referral", Medium))
Referencias$Campanas1 <- "Referencias"

Total <- rbind(Directo,Búsquedas,Adwords, Social_Media, Email, Referencias, RRSS)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than subsetting, modifying, then `rbind`ing back together, I think it is cleaner to just modify the original data.

I'm not going to try to do everything because there is not data to test so I'll probably make a typo, and the principle should generalize. Something like this:

```
Total_Content$Campanas1 <- NA # initialize this column in case it is not there yet

Total_Content$Campanas1[grepl("\\direct\\", Total_Content$source)] <- "Directo"
Total_Content$Campanas1[grepl("google", Total_Content$source)
                        & grepl("organic", Total_Content$medium)] <- "Búsquedas"
```

And so on. If you don't like typing `Total_Content` many times, you can use `with()`. You could use the same technique with `ifelse`:

```
Total <- Total_Content
Total$Campanas1 <- with(Total, ifelse(grepl("\\direct\\", source), "Directo",
                       ifelse(grepl("google", source)
                              & grepl("organic", medium), "Búsquedas",
                           ifelse(...))))
```

You could also use `dplyr` to save some typing. It would look something like this (you could also nest the `ifelse` in `dplyr`):

```
library(dplyr)
Total <- mutate(Total_Content,
    Campanas1 = NA,
    Campanas1 = ifelse(grepl("\\direct\\", source), "Directo", Campanas1),
    Campanas1 = ifelse(grepl("google", source)
                       & grepl("organic", medium), "Búsquedas", Campanas1))
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor, i'll try this. But other important concern is: How to simplify this regex from Referencias? And how to be sure it is not mixing (making troubles) with other regex? It's there a package to do this search and replace and "label" the results in a different column?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean. Maybe you could 10 or 15 rows of example input data and what you want the output to be.

Comment: With my method, `Campanas1` is initialized to `NA`. You could put the results of Referencias in another column `Campanas2`, and look to see which rows it picks up---see if it is only `NA`.

Comment: If Referencias is supposed to be everything left after all the others, nested `ifelse()` statements can also work. Very hard to know without example input/output.

Comment: My big concern is that when using `summarize` from dplyr, the totals of the Original `data.frame` and the new `data.frame` don't match. I'll edit the question with some input. Thanks.

Comment: Use `mutate`, not `summarize`! You're just adding a column (I think), no need to get rid of any rows.

Comment: please se the edit on my question. As you say, it's complicated to subset and the joining it back with rbind().